# cudaBindTextureToArray in PyCuda

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

Is-there a way to bind an array that is already on the gpu to a texture using PyCuda ?

There is already a `cuda.bind_array_to_texref(cuda.make_multichannel_2d_array(...), texref)` that binds an array on the CPU to a texture, but I couldn't find the equivalent of `cudaBindTextureToArray` in PyCuda if the array is already on the device. For example, doing :

```
myArray = [1, 2, 3]
myArray_d = gpu.to_gpu(myArray)  # then performs some computations on  it, and then
cuda.bind_texture_to_array(myArray_d, texref)
```

Comment: Isn't `pycuda.driver.TextureReference.set_array()` what you want?

Comment: great, thanks! :) (you can add that as an answer and I'll validate)

Comment: the array passed to set_array is an array on the GPU, right?

Comment: Yes, a `pycuda.driver.Array`. If you have linear memory use `set_address` or `set_address_2d`for pitched linear memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to bind an existing CUDA array in GPU memory to a texture reference, then `pycuda.driver.TextureReference.set_array()` is probably what you want. Note the PyCUDA is built on the driver API, so the call you are looking for is actually `cuTexRefSetArray` rather than `cudaBindTextureToArray`.